# How do I get my MenuActivity to show up?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am following the patterns that are used in the Compass example in a new project and have most of the logic working.  However, when I tap while my live card is displayed I hear the 'click' noise but my menu activity doesn't display.  I think that I am missing a piece of the puzzle, but I have not been able to figure out what as of yet.

When I tap, besides the click, I also see this in logcat:

```
01-08 10:02:26.796: I/ActivityManager(196): START {flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.example.speeddisplay/.SpeedDisplayMenuActivity} from pid -1
```

So it looks like it should be starting my activity, but it doesn't show up.  Here are some pieces of relevant code...although I am not sure where the issue is.

Service portion in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.example.speeddisplay.service.SpeedService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drive_50"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voiceinput_speeddisplay" />
    </service>
```

onStartCommand method in SpeedService.java:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    }
    if (liveCard == null) {
        liveCard = timelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);
        speedRenderer = new SpeedRenderer(this, speedManager);
        liveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true);
        liveCard.getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(speedRenderer);

        // Display the options menu when the live card is tapped.
        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, SpeedDisplayMenuActivity.class);
        menuIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        liveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, menuIntent, 0));
        liveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);

        if(Constants.DEBUG){
            Log.d(TAG, "liveCard published");
        }
    }

    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Here is my SpeedDisplayMenuActivity.java.   None of these methods are getting called.

```
public class SpeedDisplayMenuActivity extends Activity {

private SpeedService.SpeedBinder speedService;
private boolean mResumed;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("Service Stuff", "Service connected.");
        }
        if (service instanceof SpeedService.SpeedBinder) {
            speedService = (SpeedService.SpeedBinder) service;
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("Service Stuff", "service was an instance of " + service.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(Constants.DEBUG){
        Log.e("Menu", "Created.");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bindService(new Intent(this, SpeedService.class), mConnection, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(Constants.DEBUG){
        Log.e("Menu", "Resumed.");
    }
    super.onResume();
    mResumed = true;
    openOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(Constants.DEBUG){
        Log.e("Menu", "Paused.");
    }
    super.onPause();
    mResumed = false;
}

@Override
public void openOptionsMenu() {
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.e("Options Menu", "Open");
    }
    if (mResumed && speedService != null) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("Options Menu", "Open with correct params");
        }
        super.openOptionsMenu();
    } else {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("Options Menu", "Open with INCORRECT params");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.e("Options Menu", "Created");
    }
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.speed, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.e("Options Menu", "Item Selected");
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // case R.id.read_aloud:
    // mCompassService.readHeadingAloud();
    // return true;
    case R.id.stop:
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("Options Menu", "Stop");
        }
        stopService(new Intent(this, SpeedService.class));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.e("Options Menu", "Closed");
    }
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);

    unbindService(mConnection);

    // We must call finish() from this method to ensure that the activity
    // ends either when an
    // item is selected from the menu or when the menu is dismissed by
    // swiping down.
    finish();
}
```

Does anybody see what I am missing?

Comment: Have you registered the SpeedDisplayMenuActivity in your Manifest?

Comment: I don't see SpeedDisplayMenuActivity.java it is defined in your manifest file anywhere. Did you check that ?

Comment: You guys are both awesome.  I always forget to put new activities in my Manifest....I am just used to the "normal" Android app crashing, and that is how I remember :)  Looks like the Glassware just fails gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is right, declaring the SpeedDisplayMenuActivity is the problem in this case.

I have seen cases where many other types of exceptions / crash that normally happens in Android environment is gracefully handled in Glass.

That is definitely good for the user experience, but makes little tough on development. Hopefully some kind of settings come in future to enable exceptions as well in future!

Comment: Yes, I like the graceful handling of the issue, but a message in the log would be helpful!  I'm sure they are still working on details like that.

Comment: Hopefully so. Else that will be really difficult to understand what is going on.